# Character Modeling problems- frankensteining meshes and retopo

Tags: modeling, add-on, topology, retopology

My first question on the forum.

I chose a historical person that I wanted to model.
I am an intermediate user, but I still have  trouble with modeling the human body accurately, so I am not opposed to using add-ons if they can help me save time.

I am satisfied with where I am with the head as it is really beginning to look like the person. Now I am at the point where I start to create the body, clothes and hair.  It is easy enough to grab a body mesh from another add on, but the geometry won't match the head.  If I go this route, I have to bridge two meshes that don't match precisely.

(I have a texture working for the head as well, if I bridge these, it is going to be a task getting a new texture to match.)

I am including a screen shot of the problem. I really don't know where to start.

What advice do you have?

[image]

Comment: there are tricks to reduce the topology but maybe you should first tty to work with less faces, are you sure you need so many?

Comment: You are right, it is quite a lot, but then it is also accurate to the face I want to model.  There might be a way to bake the extra detail in after, I suppose.

Comment: yes, this is probably a good idea to keep this version and to lower down the topology on a new version

Comment: So,  I have a full body model with simpler topology (not shown here) but the face isn't exactly what I want.   I also have this face and head that is almost perfect with no body.   What I would hope is not to start from scratch, of course, and I don't know how to combine the two models  if they aren't almost alike.

Comment: have you tried to simplified the current head? Delete one edge out of 2, or maybe try Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide but it may give bad result

Comment: The Un-Subdivide has produced a promising result.  I will see what I can do with the simplified mesh.

Answer (score 0):

1.I used unsubdivide

2.I enabled statistics, and then I saw that the body had 42 vertices on the neck and the head had 46 vertices.

3 I chose adding vertices body because I thought deleting edge loops on the head might just get rid of some details I liked.

4.I prepared the body loops by adding edge loops with the mirror modifier on.

5. Bridge edge loops worked.

[image: bridge edge loops]